# Second button in linear layout not displaying

Tags: android-layout

I have a layout for an Android activity in which the second button is not displaying:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#659EC7"
android:weightSum="4"
>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Top Text"
    android:textSize="30dip"
    android:gravity="center"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"  android:weightSum="4">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Button1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Button1" 
        android:onClick="onButton1Click" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Button2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:onClick="onButton2Click" 
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put **android:orientation= "vertical"** in the LinearLayout that is containing both the buttons

Comment: That worked great, thanks!  I've been approaching layouts like html/css since I'm a web app/db developer, and am finding how they differ piece by piece.

Comment: This helped me too - can you tell me why it was necessary?

Comment: By default the orientation is "Horizontal". The second button was not shown because the width of first button is set to "fill_parent" and it takes all the available space, hence forcing the second button out of the scope. If we set orientation to "Vertical" then it doesn't show this issue.